# substr apenas com string maior que 4 caracter

Tags: php

Uso o `substr` dessa forma:

```
$conta = "ABCDE";
echo substr($conta, -1);
```

Ele me retorna `ABCD`, queria saber como executar o `substr` apenas em string que conter mais de 4 caracter.

Comment: Tentou contar os caracteres ou isso geral algum problema ou ainda não é possível de fazer?

Comment: Ué, temos maníacos de downvotes aqui?

Comment: Por que zerou nossa resposta?

Comment: Você quer pegar tudo que vier depois destes 4 caracteres, ou você quer limitar para 4 caracteres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu notei que todos usaram `-1`, mas isto faria que algo como:

- `ABCDEFGH` retornará `H`
- `ABCDEFGHI` retornará `HI`

Eu realmente fiquei na duvida se você quer pegar a parte da `string` que vem **depois** dos 4 caracteres ou se você quer limitar para 4 caracteres, se deseja limitar para 4 então creio que deveria fazer uma adaptação para isto:

```
$conta = "ABCDE";
echo strlen($conta) > 4 ? substr($conta, 0, 4) : $conta;
```

Então no exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/sJSWce) pode notar que retorna isto:

```
$conta = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";

echo strlen($conta) > 4 ? substr($conta, -1) : $conta, PHP_EOL; // M

echo strlen($conta) > 4 ? substr($conta, 0, 4) : $conta, PHP_EOL; // ABCD
```

Comment: Muito bem observado. Todos foram no impulso do AP de já ter colocado a chamada errônea da função kkk

Comment: Porque isso é um detalhe secundário na pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno sim, concordo que dentro do perguntado foi respondido exatamente o que foi pedido (dentro da compreensão), mas respondi apenas por esforço mesmo, isso não invalida nada do que foi respondido pelos demais, é apenas um adicional.

Comment: Sim, sim. Meu comentário foi em resposta ao Anderson, sua resposta tá ótima.

Comment: `preg_match('~(\w{4})\w*(\w)~', $conta, $match);` :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert legal que se adicionar o modificador `u` ae suporta unicode :D

Comment: Bem observado, não tinha nem notado

Answer (score 5):

Tentes fazer desta forma:

```
$conta = "ABCDE";
echo strlen($conta) > 4 ? substr($conta, -1) : $conta;
```

Answer (score 4):

É só fazer um `if` contando os caracteres com a função [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

```
$conta = "ABCDE";
if(strlen($conta) > 4){
    $conta = substr($conta, -1);
}
echo $conta;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função strlen pra contar [STRLEN](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

```
<?php
$str = 'abcdef';
echo strlen($str); // 6 caracteres

$str = ' ab cd ';
echo strlen($str); // 7 caracteres, pôs espaço conta
?>
```